# Does an asp.net common page to CRUD all the tables in DB exist?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want a page for super admin to CRUD all the tables in DB. Admin can use one asp.net page to select specific Table on a dropdownlist and can perform CRUD operation on that page.

I think that's a common topic for db access, searched but not found such module. Can anyone give me  advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[ASP.NET Dynamics Data](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee845452%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) might be what you need.

> Dynamic Data supports scaffolding, which is a way to automatically
>   generate Web pages for each table in the database. Scaffolding lets
>   you create a functional Web site for viewing and editing data based on
>   the schema of the data. You can easily customize scaffolding elements
>   or create new ones to override the default behavior.

Comment: Thank you, that sounds helpful．I'll check it.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't exist as a built in feature so you'll have to implement it by yourself from scratch.

Assuming you are using SQL Server, a good start point is by querying system tables suchas systables and syscolumns, to set up the screen and later set up the CRUD operations.